# Migrate mysql data to multi tables with new schema

Tags: mysql, database-migration

In the past i created the unlucky mysql schema below and cleaned it now in some points ... This is the baddest part:

```
|ID|ParentID |listing1|image1|comment1|listing2|image2|comment2|listing3|image3|comment3
|1 |50       |abc     |img1  |abc     |xyz     |img2  |xyz     |qwe     |img3  |qwe
|2 |51       |abd     |img1  |abd     |vyz     |img2  |vyz     |qwz     |img3  |qwz
|3 |52       |rtz     |img1  |rtz     |ghj     |img2  |ghj     |bnm     |img3  |bnm
```

Now i created the new structure for the old data:

Table1 (listings):

```
|ID|ParentID|listing|comment
|1 | 50     |abc    |abc 
|2 | 50     |xyz    |xyz
|3 | 50     |qwe    |qwe
|4 | 51     |adb    |adb
```

Table2 (media):

```
|ID|ParentID|image
|1 | 50     |img1   
|2 | 50     |img2   
|3 | 50     |img3   
|4 | 51     |img1
```

My problem is how to get the old values in the new schema. My first idea is to write a php foreach to fetch the values, store them and insert them again but how ... Or could i do it directly in mysql?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I would also do this with the help of PHP and quite a few MySQL queries. But that's just because I am used to that. If I had to use MySQL only I would really struggle. Apart from this, I do believe you have to make your question a bit more specific. You have problems using MySQL in PHP? Or do you know how to do that, but do you have no idea how to write the queries to SELECT and INSERT data? PS: Some people simply export, use a text-editor, and then import. If the dataset is small this can be the quickest way.

Comment: Thanks. Okay then my first idea was correct. I work with pdo and write queries are no problem, but i have no i ideas how to fetch the elements as separated "items" from mysql. So if php is the way, that is my problem here .... copy paste with an editor is a bit time intensive because there are already some data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create proper table1 and table2 with autoincrement

```
create table1 (
  id int(11) not null autoincrement primary key,
  parentID int(11) not null ,
  listing varchar(255),
  comment varchar(255)
)
;
create table2 (
  id int(11) not null autoincrement primary key,
  parentID int(11) not null ,
  image varchar(255)
)
;
```

then a couple of insert select based on Union

```
insert into table1 (parentID, listing, comment)
select parentID, listing1, comment1
from old_table
union 
select parentID, listing2, comment2
from old_table
union 
select parentID, listing3, comment3
from old_table
;




insert into tabl2 (parentID, image)

select parentID, image1
from old_table
union 
select parentID, image2
from old_table
union 
select parentID, image3
from old_table
```

Comment: Great, thank you! Not very difficult but you have to know how :)